# can .net framework 4 works on top of windows xp?

Tags: .net-4.0, windows-xp

I tried to run a small application that I've written using VS2010 on my old Windows XP desktop. I got the yellow screen of death showing me a portion of the web.config with assemblies.

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
```

It looks like it didn't like the 4.0 framework. I re-wrote it, targeting 3.5 framework, this time it worked perfectly.

I'd like to know if I can install .net framework 4.0 on top of Windows XP?

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [system requirements](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=9cfb2d51-5ff4-4491-b0e5-b386f32c0992&displaylang=en#SystemRequirements) indicate that Windows XP is supported as long as you have SP3 installed.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's possible. .NET 4.0 works fine on Windows XP machines. Just make sure SP3 is installed first.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can :) Just [download it](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=9cfb2d51-5ff4-4491-b0e5-b386f32c0992&displaylang=en) and install

Answer (score 2):

See [MSDN](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=9cfb2d51-5ff4-4491-b0e5-b386f32c0992&displaylang=en#SystemRequirements), you need WinXP SP3