# .Net framework 4 Applications for Windows XP

Tags: c#, windows, .net-4.0, windows-xp, desktop-application

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [can .net framework 4 works on top of windows xp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3767651/can-net-framework-4-works-on-top-of-windows-xp)

We are considering various framework and languages options to develop our database driven Desktop Application for our target market which, unfortunately, abundantly uses Windows XP in their systems. Can anyone please confirm that if we develop a desktop application in C#/.NET framework 4.0, will that application be able to run on Windows XP? I understand that to run .net developed applications, we need to have .net framework installed in end-users' system so my 2nd question is: can we install .net Framework on Windows XP (with no service pack installed on that)? 
Waiting to be enlightened by your expert answers.

Comment: This question is probably more appropriate on super user.

Answer (score 4):

It's not clear why you think you've got two questions here - they're both basically "does .NET 4 run on Windows XP" which is easily answered by the [system requirements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z6watww%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) page.

That shows that .NET 4 works on XP Professional, XP Home Edition and XP Professional x64 edition. It does *not* work (or at least isn't supported) on Media Center, Tablet PC or Starter editions.

I would *expect* it to be an optional install via Windows Update, so you may find that *some* of your customers already have it installed, but plenty of others don't.